# Python "executes" html, but not the js within

Tags: javascript, python, html

sorry for the noob question, but I'm pretty new to all this.
So to simplify, I have a test.html file that looks like this:

```
<body>
    ... // Part A of HTML
    <table id="table"></table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script> // js code that sets the innerHTML of the table
</body>
```

Now if I run my test.html file, everything's displayed, Part A, as well as the table.

However, my project requires that I now use a local python server, so I set up a server.py file, as well as a test.py file that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

print('Content-type: text/html')

file = open('test.html', 'r')
html = file.read()
file.close()

print(html)
```

Now if I run localhost:8000/test.py in my browser (Firefox), Part A of my HTML is displayed, but not my table anymore.

So is there a simple way to make Python "execute" the js code within the  of the HTML as well, so that my table appears as well, or is there no other way, but to use external resources (like ExecJS, Naked, etc), which I'm not sure I'm allowed to use for my project.

Thanks in advance guys. Take care.

Comment: No chance this is going to happen with a print statement... you'll need external libraries...

Comment: something like simplehttpserver module or flask would be better to use here

Comment: Try `localhost:8000/test.js` in your browser. If it doesn't show anything, that would mean your javascript code doesn't work because the server was unable to find it for the client. Alternatively, you can try to put your JS code in the HTML with `<script></script>`.

Comment: If you run that Python script in the terminal does it print the HTML that you expect? If so, then the browser _should_ execute the JavaScript just like it would if you loaded the HTML from a file. However, you really should send a blank line after the header line, and it would be better if you sent proper HTML data, with a proper `doctype` and `<html>` tag so that the browser doesn't execute it in quirks mode. OOPS! I just noticed that your JavaScript is coming from "test.js". The browser may be having problems finding that file, depending on how your server is configured.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. So to clear the potential js file problem, I removed the <script src="test.js"></script> line in my test.html file, which I replaced by a <script></script> tag that surrounds my whole code from the JS file. I'm still getting the same thing: if I run the html file, the table set by the JS code shows, but if I run localhost:8000/test.py, the html part shows, but the table doesn't appear anymore. And yes I have proper doctype and html tags, I didn't include them in the initial post to shorten the code ;-)